# WordPress Health Tool reporting version control as a critical issue

Tags: automatic-updates, git, version-control

I use git to deploy my production site, and as a result, the sites Health tool is reporting a critical issue due to the auto-updates not working when a site is under version control.

[image]

To be honest, it wouldn't be an issue to allow auto-updates, and just periodically commit the production changes.  Is there a way of just forcing them and solving/suppressing this 'critical issue'?

Comment: Why would you want auto-updates if you have version control?

Comment: That's not really my point. It's about why WordPress thinks that having version control warrants disabling auto-updates, and furthermore why the health tool sees that as a critical issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the [`site_status_tests`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/site_status_tests/) filter, to e.g. remove the *asynchronous background updates* tests:

```
add_filter( 'site_status_tests', function ( $tests ) {
    unset( $tests['async']['background_updates'] );
    return $tests;
} );
```

But one could argue that this is just hiding information from the user.

Ticket [#46733](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/46733) suggests instead e.g. "...*ignored tests section, hidden away like the Passed tests*", so the user can still find this information.

But it's currently closed as `maybelater`.

One can also create custom tests, through the `site_status_tests` filter, as explained in the [dev notes](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/04/25/site-health-check-in-5-2/). Perhabs a custom test wrapper around `WP_Site_Health->get_test_background_updates()` to modify as needed, but that sounds unstable. Maybe one could look into a wrapper that uses  `WP_Site_Health_Auto_Updates->run_tests()` instead? Though probably best to join the discussion about this on Trac or [GitHub](https://github.com/WordPress/health-check/) to change this.

**Update:** WordPress 5.3 will change the message from *failure* to *warning* (see [#47982](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/47982))